# Execute BYTE array in detoured function

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, byte, hook

I know it's a long post but it's mostly code and pictures, it's a quick read! First of all, here is what I'm trying to do:

**I'm trying to execute a BYTE array in a detoured function in order to go back to the original code as if I didn't detour anyhting** Here is my code:

DllMain (DetourAddress is all that matter):

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved  )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        AllocConsole();
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

        DetourAddress((void*)HookAddress, (void*)&DetourFunc);

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        FreeConsole();
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

DetourAddress (code is self-explanatory, I think):

```
void DetourAddress(void* funcPtr, void* hook)
{
    // write jmp
    BYTE cmd[5] =
    { 
        0xE9, //jmp
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  //address
    };

    // make memory readable/writable
    DWORD dwProtect;
    VirtualProtect(funcPtr, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwProtect); 

    // read bytes about to be replaced
    ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)funcPtr, mem, 5, NULL);

    // write jmp in cmd
    DWORD offset = ((DWORD)hook - (DWORD)funcPtr - 5);  // (dest address) - (source address) - (jmp size)
    memcpy(&cmd[1], &offset, 4); // write address into jmp
    WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)funcPtr, cmd, 5, 0); // write jmp

    // reprotect
    VirtualProtect(funcPtr, 5, dwProtect, NULL);
}
```

DetourFunc:

```
_declspec(naked) void DetourFunc()
{
    __asm
    {
        PUSHFD
        PUSHAD
    }

    printf("function detoured\n");

    __asm
    {
        POPAD
        POPFD
    }

    // make memory readable/writable
    DWORD dwProtect;
    VirtualProtect(mem, 6, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwProtect); 

    pByteExe();

    // reprotect
    VirtualProtect(mem, 6, dwProtect, NULL);

    __asm
    {
        jmp HookReturnAddress
    }
}
```

And finaly the global variables, typedef for pByteExe() and includes:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

DWORD   HookAddress         = 0x08B1418,
        HookReturnAddress   = HookAddress+5;

typedef void ( * pFunc)();
BYTE mem[6] = { 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xC3 };
pFunc pByteExe = (pFunc) &mem
```

As you can see in DetourFunc, I'm trying to execute my byte array (mem) directly. Using OllyDbg, this gets me there:

[image]

Which is exactly the bytes I'm trying to execute. Only problem is that it gives me an Access violation error when executing... Any idea why? I would have thought "VirtualProtect(mem, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwProtect);" would have made it safe to access... Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I just realized something wierd was happening... when I "Step into" with ollydbg, the mem instructions are correct, but as soon as I scroll a little, they change back to this:

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you checked the return result of `VirtualProtect`? Also the VirtualProtect page on MSDN says to call `FlushInstructionCache` after modifying instructions.

Comment: The error code for VirtualProtect is 998 (Invalid access to memory location.) even after I called FlushInstructionCache after every instructions modifications. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I found something new... edited my post

Comment: It is probably raising an access violation because `byte ptr ds:[esi+4]` is inaccessible. But your overall design is flawed. Instructions on x86 are variable-sized. You are executing four bytes, but what if the instruction is not 4 bytes in size? You are also trying to `ret` from code that may have altered the stack. You need to go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot the module offset...

```
DWORD module = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
DWORD real_address = module + (DWORD)ADDRESS;
```

ADDRESS have to of course relative to your module. (The module offset isn't allways the same)

And btw. why you take WriteProcessMemory, when you inject your DLL? A simple memcpy is enought...